# Get Token by loging in with External Providers using OpenIddict

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, google-authentication, openiddict

I have an API with ASP.NET Core which will be consumed by native mobile apps(currently UWP, Android) and I'm trying to implement a way that clients can sign up and log in with both username/password and external providers such as Google and Facebook. now I'm using `openIddict` and my `ExternalProviderCallback` must return local tokens which I assume currently returns cookie! (I've Copied most of the codes from somewhere) and also it seems it's not the AuthorizationCodeFlow which I assume that is the correct way!

now here is my Startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(c => Configuration);
        services.AddEntityFramework();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            //Setting some configurations
            config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AutomaticChallenge = false;
            config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && 
                    context.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && 
                    context.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        services.AddOpenIddict()
            .AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .UseJsonWebTokens()
            .AddMvcBinders()
            .EnableAuthorizationEndpoint(Configuration["Authentication:OpenIddict:AuthorizationEndPoint"])
            .EnableTokenEndpoint(Configuration["Authentication:OpenIddict:TokenEndPoint"])
            .AllowPasswordFlow()
            .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
            .AllowImplicitFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
            .DisableHttpsRequirement()
            .AddEphemeralSigningKey()
            .SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2))
            .SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        services.AddSingleton<DbSeeder>();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.SslPort = 44380;
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DbSeeder dbSeeder)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseOAuthValidation();

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"],
            CallbackPath = "/signin-google",
            Scope = { "email" }
        });
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"],
            AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"],
            CallbackPath = "/signin-facebook",
            Scope = { "email" }
        });

        app.UseOpenIddict();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        try
        {
            dbSeeder.SeedAsync().Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is AccountController Which is Doing External Providers Job:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountsController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    #region Constructor

    public AccountsController(ApplicationDbContext context,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(context, signInManager, userManager)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    #endregion Constructor


    #region External Authentication Providers 

    // GET: /api/Accounts/ExternalLogin 
    [HttpGet("ExternalLogin/{provider}")]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        switch (provider.ToLower())
        {
            case "facebook":
            case "google":
            case "twitter":
                // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
                var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback",
                    "Accounts", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
                var properties =
                    SignInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
                return Challenge(properties, provider);
            default:
                return BadRequest(new
                {
                    Error = $"Provider '{provider}' is not supported."
                });
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallBack")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null,
        string remoteError = null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (remoteError != null)
            {
                throw new Exception(remoteError);
            }
            var info = await SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR: No login info available.");
            }
            var user = await UserManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);
            if (user == null)
            {
                var emailKey =
                    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress";
                var email = info.Principal.FindFirst(emailKey).Value;
                user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    var now = DateTime.Now;
                    var idKey =
                        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier";
                    var username = string.Format("{0}{1}", info.LoginProvider,
                        info.Principal.FindFirst(idKey).Value);
                    user = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        UserName = username,
                        Email = email,
                        CreatedDate = now,
                        LastModifiedDate = now
                    };
                    await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "SomePass4ExProvider123+-");
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Registered");
                    user.EmailConfirmed = true;
                    user.LockoutEnabled = false;
                }
                await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            // create the auth JSON object 
            var auth = new
            {
                type = "External",
                providerName = info.LoginProvider
            };

            // output a <SCRIPT> tag to call a JS function registered into the parent window global scope
            return Content("<script type=\"text / javascript\">" +
                           "window.opener.externalProviderLogin(" +
                           JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auth) + ");" +
                           "window.close();" + "</script>", "text/html");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(new {Error = ex.Message});
        }
    }

    [HttpPost("Logout")]
    public IActionResult Logout()
    {
        if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            SignInManager.SignOutAsync().Wait();
        }
        return Ok();
    }

    #endregion External Authentication Providers 
}
```

and Lastly ConnectController Which will Generate Tokens :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ConnectController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ConnectController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpPost("token"), Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Token(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);

            #region Authenticate User

            if (user == null)
            {
                // Return bad request if the user doesn't exist
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "Invalid username or password"
                });
            }
            if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user) ||
                (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user)))
            {

                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The specified user cannot sign in."
                });
            }

            if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
            {
                // Return bad request if the password is invalid
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "Invalid username or password"
                });
            }

            // The user is now validated, so reset lockout counts, if necessary
            if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
            {
                await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
            }

            #endregion

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name, null);

            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
                user.Id,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name, 
                user.DisplayName??user.UserName,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);


            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(principal, request, new AuthenticationProperties());

            return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
        if (request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        {
            var info = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticateInfoAsync(
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);



            var id = info.Principal.FindFirst(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject)?.Value;
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The refresh token is no longer valid."
                });
            }

            if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user))
            {
                return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                {
                    Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    ErrorDescription = "The user is no longer allowed to sign in."
                });
            }
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name, null);

            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject,
                user.Id,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

            identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                user.DisplayName ?? user.UserName,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);

            // ... add other claims, if necessary.

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(principal,request, info.Properties);

            // Ask OpenIddict to generate a new token and return an OAuth2 token response.
            return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // Return bad request if the request is not for password grant type
        return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
        {
            Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
            ErrorDescription = "The specified grant type is not supported."
        });
    }
    private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal,
        OpenIdConnectRequest request,
       AuthenticationProperties properties = null)
    {

        // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, properties,
            OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        if (!request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        {
            //TODO : // Include resources and scopes, **as APPROPRIATE**
            // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application.
            // Note: the offline_access scope must be granted
            // to allow OpenIddict to return a refresh token.
            ticket.SetScopes(new[]
            {
                /* openid: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                /* email: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                /* profile: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                /* offline_access: */ OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess,
                /* roles: */ OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
            }.Intersect(request.GetScopes()));
        }
        return ticket;
    }

    #region Authorization code, implicit and implicit flows

    // Note: to support interactive flows like the code flow,
    // you must provide your own authorization endpoint action:

    [Authorize, HttpGet("authorize")]
    public IActionResult Authorize(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and this is how I send request :

**https://localhost:44380/api/Accounts/ExternalLogin/Google?returnUrl=https://localhost:44380**

which returns successfully to my ExternalLoginCallback Action in AccountsController but no JWT tokens are sent back to user as normal PasswordGrantFlow.

Please if it's possible send me code here and don't redirect me somewhere else cause I'm totally new to server side and also I've done my searches before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Velusia sample - authorization code flow](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia).

You can tweak your authorization endpoint if you want to immediately redirect your users to a specified social provider instead of returning them to the login page:

```
[HttpGet("~/connect/authorize")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
{
    Debug.Assert(request.IsAuthorizationRequest(),
        "The OpenIddict binder for ASP.NET Core MVC is not registered. " +
        "Make sure services.AddOpenIddict().AddMvcBinders() is correctly called.");

    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Resolve the optional provider name from the authorization request.
        // If no provider is specified, call Challenge() to redirect the user
        // to the login page defined in the ASP.NET Core Identity options.
        var provider = (string) request.GetParameter("identity_provider");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(provider))
        {
            return Challenge();
        }

        // Ensure the specified provider is supported.
        if (!HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticationSchemes()
            .Where(description => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(description.DisplayName))
            .Any(description => description.AuthenticationScheme == provider))
        {
            return Challenge();
        }

        // When using ASP.NET Core Identity and its default AccountController,
        // the user must be redirected to the ExternalLoginCallback action
        // before being redirected back to the authorization endpoint.
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider,
            Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new
            {
                ReturnUrl = Request.PathBase + Request.Path + Request.QueryString
            }));

        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    // Retrieve the application details from the database.
    var application = await _applicationManager.FindByClientIdAsync(request.ClientId, HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    if (application == null)
    {
        return View("Error", new ErrorViewModel
        {
            Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidClient,
            ErrorDescription = "Details concerning the calling client application cannot be found in the database"
        });
    }

    // Flow the request_id to allow OpenIddict to restore
    // the original authorization request from the cache.
    return View(new AuthorizeViewModel
    {
        ApplicationName = application.DisplayName,
        RequestId = request.RequestId,
        Scope = request.Scope
    });
}
```

Comment: I had seen that sample it's client is MVC,not native mobile app which means it's irrelevant to my question but anyway I just Copy Pasted those codes form sample and now I get 404 NotFound on connect/token , I checked out that every call that start without api segment is logged https/localhost:44380/index.html !!! but those which start with it are getting 401 ! it's strange! I wonder why there is no tutorial for creating an API for Native Mobile apps which supports TokenBasedAuth (local + google) though it's very common these days! and no real documentation, just old useless not workingsamples!

Comment: @HesamKashefi the fact the client is a MVC application doesn't change anything to how the code flow works: the protocol is the same. I tested this code with the code flow sample before posting it, so it works (despite what you claim). I guess you're just doing something wrong.

Comment: thanks a lot, I found out that there is a UseWhenExtentionMethod which I didn't copy your Implementation but it was using the Microsoft Equivalent which didn't work. being a MVC Client only has impact on a beginner like me who doesn't know how to change it to API for mobile apps and all these ValidateAntiForgeryTokens which my only solution is to remove them, and one more thing ! I don't know how to deal with this Accept Page in API approach and also where should I persist the newly Authenticated User because I'm getting Exception on Accept Action because it can't find the user

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helped me too.

Comment: I want to achieve exactly this scenario (redirect to a specific social provider based on a query param to the /connect/authorize endpoint), but I just can't get it working with OpenIddict 3 and the latest AspNetCore5 Identity. I can see it is performing the external auth, but I finally get redirected to /Identity/Account/Login, instead of back through to the oidc client. I'm sure it I'm missing something obvious, but I can't figure it out. Any help, please?!?

Comment: Figured it out - I think the Identity pages/code has been reorganized since this question/answer. I solve it by using 'ChallengeResult', but in Login.cshtml.cs > OnGetAsync.